# Bookmarking in pdf generated using velocity template

Tags: java, itext, velocity

I have huge data, the data will be used to generate PDF using velocity template. I have index page generated using .vm file which is a table. I should provide bookmarking from index page to other pages which is intended to.

I tried using just href in HTML.

**index.vm:**

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>
1
</td>
<td>
<a href="#go">chapter1</a>
<td>
</tr>
</table>
```

**assembly.vm:**

```
<table>
<tr>
<p1 id="go">assembly1</p>
</tr>
</table>
```

It's expected to have link in index page and on click on it, go to that respective content page.

Comment: You want to generate this .vm templates to PDF?

Comment: @Paul.F-G Yes, i am using .vm templates for pdf generation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once the pdf has been generated using itext and with .vm file,
while generating, store the description with page number in a map, this was acheived using this following code

```
HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    map.put("Title", "INDEX");
    map.put("Action", "GoTo");
    map.put("Page", String.format("%d Fit", 8));
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> kids = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,Object>>();

    for(BookMark book : BookMarks) {
        HashMap<String, Object> kid = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        kid.put("Title", book.getDescription());
        kid.put("Action", "GoTo");
        kid.put("Page", String.format("%d Fit", book.getPageNumber()));

        ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> leafs = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,Object>>();
        for(BookMark books : book.getLeaf()) {
            HashMap<String, Object> leaf = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            leaf.put("Title", books.getDescription());
            leaf.put("Action", "GoTo");
            leaf.put("Page", String.format("%d Fit", books.getPageNumber()));
            leafs.add(leaf);
        }
        kid.put("Kids", leafs);
        kids.add(kid);
    }

    map.put("Kids", kids);
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> outlines = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,Object>>();
    outlines.add(map);
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(env.getProperty("path.generated.pdf").concat(fileName));
    PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileOutputStream(env.getProperty("path.generated.pdf").concat(catalogInfo.getCatalogName().trim().concat("raw1")).concat(".pdf")));
    stamper.setOutlines(outlines);
    stamper.setFullCompression();
    stamper.close();
    reader.close();
    File file = new File(env.getProperty("path.generated.pdf").concat(fileName)); 
    file.delete();
```

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same problem to generate PDFs from templates but I was using JSP. It is the same logic for every template engine.

To achieve it make a request on your own server to fetch the generated content from template in HTML and convert it to PDF with [flying-saucer](https://github.com/flyingsaucerproject/flyingsaucer).

[image]

So basically you'll have

**A servlet returning your generated Velocity template according to parameters**

(i.e. : http://127.0.0.1/getgeneratedpdf)

```
    dopost etc. ...
```

**Another servlet calling this first servlet with needed parameters to fetch generated content in HTML**

```
   URLConnection connection = new URL(urlOfTheServletAbove).openConnection();
   connection.setDoOutput(true); // POST
   connection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", "UTF-8");
   connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8");
   try (OutputStream output = connection.getOutputStream()) {
       // parameters is encoded query string
       output.write(parameters.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
   }
   BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
   StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
   String inputLine;
   while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) { sb.append(inputLine); }
   in.close();
```

**A PDF builder based on flying-saucer**

```
import org.xhtmlrenderer.pdf.ITextRenderer;
// ...
private static final String TMP_DIR = System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir");
// ...
File tempPdf = new File(TMP_DIR+tempPdfName);
if (!tempPdf.exists()) { tempPdf.createNewFile(); }
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(tempPdf);
new ITextRenderer() {{
    setDocumentFromString(sb.toString());
    layout();
    createPDF(fos);
}};
fos.close();
// ...
```

**Then write PDF into response**

```
void writePDFContentToResponse(File pdf, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
    InputStream fis = new FileInputStream(pdf);
    String mimeType = getServlet().getServletContext().getMimeType(pdf.getAbsolutePath());
    response.setContentType(mimeType != null ? mimeType : "application/octet-stream");
    response.setContentLength((int) pdf.length());
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=yourPDFName.pdf"); // or +pdf.getName();
    ServletOutputStream os = response.getOutputStream();
    byte[] bufferData = new byte[1024];
    int read = 0;
    while((read = fis.read(bufferData)) != -1) { os.write(bufferData, 0, read); }
    os.flush();
    os.close();
    fis.close();
    response.flushBuffer();
    Files.delete(pdf.toPath());
}
```